# create CLLocation object in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I can initialize a `CLLocation` object by providing latitude and longitude like below:

```
CLLocation *location =  [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:-43.242534 longitude:-54.93662];
```

How can I initialize a `CLLocation` object with not only latitude and longitude but also accuracy values?

Comment: http://apple.co/1WRs6Na does this method work for you?

Comment: Can you provide a example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per apple [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocation/initWithCoordinate:altitude:horizontalAccuracy:verticalAccuracy:timestamp:) you can use the following function:

```
double desired_horizontal_accuracy = 200.0 // in meters
double desired_vertical_accuracy = 200.0 // in meters
[[CLLocation alloc] initWithCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-43.242534,-54.93662)
                              altitude:-1
                    horizontalAccuracy:desired_horizontal_accuracy
                      verticalAccuracy:desired_vertical_accuracy
                             timestamp:[NSDate date]]
```

In the example, for the parameters `altitude` and `timestamp`, I put the same defaults as what the apple docs say are used on [`-initWithLatitude:longitude:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocation/initWithLatitude:longitude:)